# g_n integrable on R

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let g_n (x) = 1      if x=0

```
           sin x /x  if -n<= x <= n
           0         if x<-n  or  x>n
```

show that for every n, g_n is integrable (Lebesgue integrable) on R.

Comment: Well, what's the measure of the set of discontinuity points of each $\;g_n\;$ ... ?

Comment: what do you mean?I do not understand

Comment: Have you already studied the Riemann-Lebesgue Theorem? Check this: http://math.northwestern.edu/~scanez/courses/berkeley/math104/fall11/handouts/riemann-lebesgue.pdf

Comment: No I have't. I'll try

Comment: I do not get it. I think I need some help

Answer (score 0):

Without the R-L Theorem:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g_n(x)dx\stackrel ?=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{-n}g_n(x)dx+\int\limits_{-n}^ng_n(x)dx+\int\limits_n^\infty g_n(x)dx$$

Since each and every one of the three integrals on the RHS above exists, you can delete now that question mark (?) and we're done.

Comment: But I think we need to show that the integral from -n to n of g_n (x) exists?!?!

Comment: Well, there $\;g_n\;$ is a continuous functions with a **removable** discontinuity point at $\;x=0\;$ , so no problem at all...

Comment: But we have to show that g_n is bounded, right?

Comment: Well, isn't it obvious @Jawad ? $\;g_n(x)\;$ is non-zero in a *closed* interval and there it is continuous...well, less one removable discontinuity point.

Comment: Yes. thank you. I just wanted to the last step with no doubt. Thank you!!!

Comment: @DonAntonio: The boundedness is a matter of the interval being compact not closed (little but important difference).